# Printing out the average of values stored in an array, in a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, average

i'm trying to print out the average value in a table using javascript. Here is my code"

I have placed a for loop to loop through the array however, i only get the mean or average value as you would say of the last line of the array, for Khan.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There is no code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what this code does - assigning the last *mean* value. 
You have to store mean values with the students, or calculate it when writing to document, i.e.:

```
document.write("<td>" + 0.5*(students[i].CW50 + students[i].EX50) + "</td></tr>")
```

instead of:

```
document.write("<td>" + mean + "</td></tr>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one **mean** variable and you set it three times in your first loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
var mean = 0.5*(students[i].CW50 + students[i].EX50)
}
```

So your calculation of three means has finished before placing the values anywhere and **mean** has the value of the last calculation (i=2, Khan) because you didn't use an array (something like mean[i] = ...).

Solution: You have to do the calculation in the second loop like:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  var mean = 0.5*(students[i].CW50 + students[i].EX50);
  document.write("<tr><td>" + students[i].name + "</td>");
  document.write("<td>" + students[i].CW50 + "</td>");
  document.write("<td>" + students[i].EX50 + "</td>");
  document.write("<td>" + mean + "</td></tr>")
}
```

This way your calculation is done, the value is placed in the html and then the next iteration is processed.